# How to separate image data into x, y coordinate? (python)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a image data, How can I separate it into x, y and the value?

image data

```
[[38  0  0 ...  0  0  0]
 [46  3  0 ...  0  0  0]
 [46  3  0 ...  0  0  0]
 ...
 [74  0  0 ...  0  0  0]
 [74  0  0 ...  0  0  0]
 [74  0  0 ...  0  0  0]]
```

and their should it be?

```
x = 0, y = 0, value = 38
x = 0, y = 1, value = 46
...
```

How can I separate it in to :

```
x = []
y = []
value = []
```

only `for` loop method is work?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, I think you can use `np.indices`. Take your example:

```
>>> img
array([[38,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [46,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [46,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [74,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [74,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [74,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])

value = img.flatten()
y,x = np.indices(img.shape).reshape(-1,len(value))

>>> x
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3,
       4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> y
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
>>> value
array([38,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 46,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0, 46,  3,  0,  0,  0,
        0, 74,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 74,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 74,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0])
```

So where `x` is 0 and `y` is 0, you get `value` 38, where `x` is 0 and `y` is 1, you get `value` 46, and so on.

**Edit**: In your comment, you said you want to filter out the zeros. You can do this with `np.where` and `np.nonzero`:

```
y,x = np.where(img)

value = img[np.nonzero(img)]

>>> y
array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> x
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
>>> value
array([38, 46,  3, 46,  3, 74, 74, 74])
```

Comment: how about I want to filter 0 in value? that means, if value = 0, x , y will not record it

Comment: See my eidt, you can do that with `np.where` and `np.nonzero`

Comment: Thank for you reply, it is a big help

Answer (score 0):

if your image is colored, it's often in RGB format(3 channels), if it's grayscale, it will have 1 channel.
So the shape of the array will be `(img_height, img_width, number_of_channels)`

By understanding the shape, you can properly use the `imread` from `PIL` or `imread` from `matplotlib` to load the image, and then turn them to array using `myarray = numpy.array(your_loaded_img)`. As it's a numpy array, you can call the cell values by `myarray[x,y]`